# Writing File in Chunks using Ajax and FileReader

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, filereader, chunks

I am working on creating a file uploader, where the contents will be written to a remote server in chunks using a 3rd party API. The API provides a `WriteFileChunk()` method that takes 3 parameters, the target file path, the start position (Int64) and data (string) of bytes.

Each time FileReader receives a chunk of the maximum supported size (16kb), I need to use Ajax to pass this to a PHP file and write it using the API. I suspect that this should be done in the `onprogress` event of FileReader, however I am at somewhat of a loss given that I cannot find any similar examples.

What would be the best way to implement this using FileReader, ensuring that each chunk is uploaded before writing the next? If `onprogress` is the best choice, how can I get the current chunk data?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function uploadFile()
    {
        var files = document.getElementById('file').files;

        if (!files.length)
        {
            alert('Please select a file!');
            return;
        }

        var file = files[0];
        var first_byte = 0;
        var last_byte = file.size - 1;

        // File Reader
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = function(evt)
        {
            switch(evt.target.error.code)
            {
                case evt.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                    alert('File Not Found!');
                    break;
                case evt.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
                    alert('File is not readable');
                    break;
                case evt.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
                    break;
                    default:
                    alert('An error occurred reading this file.');
            };
        };
        reader.onprogress = function(evt)
        {
            if (evt.lengthComputable)
            {
                var percentLoaded = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
                console.log(percentLoaded + "%");

                if (percentLoaded < 100)
                {
                    $("#upload_progress").progressbar('value', percentLoaded);
                }
            }
        };
        reader.onabort = function(evt)
        {
            alert('File Upload Cancelled');
        };
        reader.onloadstart = function(evt)
        {
            $("#upload_progress").progressbar({
                value: 0,
                max: 100
            });
        };
        reader.onload = function(evt)
        {
            $("#upload_progress").progressbar('value', 100);
        };
        reader.onloadend = function(evt)
        {
            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) // DONE == 2
            {
                alert("Upload Complete!");
                //console.log(evt.target.result);
            }
        };

        var blob = file.slice(first_byte, last_byte + 1);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
    }

    fileupload_dialog = $( "#dialog-fileupload" ).dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 175,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons:
        {
            "Upload File": uploadFile
        },
        close: function()
        {
            form[ 0 ].reset();
        }
    });

    form = fileupload_dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event )
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        uploadFile();
    });

    $("#file_upload a").click(function()
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        fileupload_dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main challenge here is that the `FileReader` will need to read the entire file into memory before it return any usable data to us via the `result` property, meaning you can't grab chunks from the file while the file is being read (and the progress event won't provide/point to any data):

> This property [`result`] is only valid after the read operation is
>   complete [...]

<sup>[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Properties)</sup>

As the complete file is loaded into memory there wouldn't really be any benefits chunking the read process (if it was possible), besides from reducing a little lag perhaps between the two processes.

I would suggest the following approach based on the above:

- Load the entire file into memory, but as `ArrayBuffer`
- Calculate number of segments required (`Math.ceil(fileLength/chunkSize)`)
- Create a chunk using a `Uint8Array` view for the `ArrayBuffer` using the offset and chunk length arguments
- Send the chunk, wait for response asynchronously, continue to next chunk until left length is <= 0 byte.

The chunk can be converted to a Blob before sending it, if needed:

```
var chunkBlob = new Blob([chunk], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
```

### Example process

A pseudo server example waiting arbitrarily 100ms between each block of 16kb:

```js
file.onchange = function(e) {
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onprogress = function(e) {progress.value = e.loaded / e.total};
  fr.onload = startUpload.bind(fr);
  progress.style.display = "inline-block";
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
}

// Main upload code
function startUpload() {
  
  // calculate sizes
  var chunkSize = 16<<10;
  var buffer = this.result;
  var fileSize = buffer.byteLength;
  var segments = Math.ceil(fileSize / chunkSize);
  var count = 0;
  progress.value = 0;

  // start "upload"
  (function upload() {
    var segSize = Math.min(chunkSize, fileSize - count * chunkSize);
    if (segSize > 0) {
      var chunk = new Uint8Array(buffer, count++ * chunkSize, segSize); // get a chunk
      progress.value = count / segments;
      // send chunk to server (here pseudo cycle for demo purpose)
      setTimeout(upload, 100); // when upload OK, call function again for the next block
    }
    else {
      alert("Done");
      progress.style.display = "none";
   }
  })()
}
```

```css
body {font:16px sans-serif;margin:20px 0 0 20px}
```

```html
<label>Select any file: <input type=file id="file"></label><br>
<progress id="progress" value=0 max=1 style="display:none" />
```